# Working With System.Drawing.Region

Tags: c#, winforms, graphics

I've made a test `WindowForm` application that takes a snapshot of the window by it's boundaries. But I can't seem to give GetBounds() what it needs. He wants graphics but it already contains the bounds, I just want his point and size:

```
private void CaptureBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Region region = GetRegionByHWnd(GetForegroundWindow());

    Rectangle rectangle = new Rectangle(
                                        region.GetBounds().Location,
                                        region.GetBounds().Size);

    CaptureImage(rectangle.Location, Point.Empty, rectangle.Size);
}
```

Did that problem occur to anyone before, or knows how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> For getBound some windows for you can
>   use ClientRectangle property , This
>   property returns bound form and this
>   dll  (ScreenCaptureLib.dll) helps you
>   for getImage in the desktop.

http://www.codeproject.com/script/Articles/ViewDownloads.aspx?aid=19415

Answer (score 1):

First, `Region` implements `IDisposable`, so you should be wrapping it in a using statement or calling Dispose when you done with it.

Other than that we will need to see your code for `GetRegionByHWnd` and `CaptureImage`.  Do you really even need that code at all?  Why won't `someWindow.Bounds` work for you?

Comment: Interesting, you got an example of "someWindow.Bonds"? I know theres desktop bonds but not to a window. I need the foreground(active) window

Comment: [Form.Bounds](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.bounds.aspx), but that will only help you if you can get a reference to a System.Windows.Forms.Form, which it doesn't look like you are doing.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps that helps: [RECTANGLE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.rectangle.aspx)

I don't know your methods like captureimage. But Perhaps you need the relative position to the control?
[Point to Client](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.pointtoclient.aspx) / [Point to Screen](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.pointtoscreen.aspx)

If not, please tell the data you expect to get and what you receive.

Also take a lookt to the [RECT MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.rect.aspx) type instead of the Rectangle type.

Some good articles are here:

http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/csharp/cs_graphics/screencaptures/article.php/c6139

http://cid-32fd2eb6551ddb56.office.live.com/self.aspx/.Public/CaptureWindow.rar?sa=170500830

http://winapi.freetechsecrets.com/win32/WIN32Capturing_an_Image.htm

Regards